# PHP doesn't display error messages for my form validation

Tags: php, validation

I can't see why the variable `$errorMessage` will not set with array errors.

I'm trying to make a form validation. This PHP is all at the top of the page `register.php`

This is the page I'm trying to work on. I hope I can resolve this!

```
<?php
   session_start();
   // include("includes/connect.php");
   include ("includes/html.php");


   if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $error = array(); 

      //username
      if (empty($_POST['username'])){
         $error[] = 'Please Enter a Username';
      }
      else if (ctype_alnum ($_POST['username'])){
         $userName = $_POST['username'];
      } 
      else {
         $error[] = 'Username Must Consist Letters and Numbers Only';
      }

      //email
      if (empty($_POST['email'])){
         $error[] = 'Please Enter an Email';
      } 
      else if (!preg_mach ("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)
↪*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$",$_POST['email'])) {
         $email = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['username']);
      } 
      else {
         $error[] = 'Your Email Address is Invalid';
      }

      //password
      if (empty($_POST['password'])){
         $error[] = 'Please Enter a password';
      } 
      else if ($_POST['password']!==$_POST['password2']){
         $error[] = 'Your Password Did Not Match';
      }
      else {
         $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_post['password']);
      }
   }

   if (empty ($error)){
      //good info
   }
   else {
      $errorMessage = '<span class="error">';
      foreach ($error as $key => $e){
         $errorMessage.= "$e";
      }
      $errorMessage.= '</span> <br /><br />';
   }

?>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but that's a pretty [weak email validator](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

Comment: Where do You print that `$errorMessage` variable?

Comment: Anyway, You could do this in a little prettier way: `$errorMessage = '<span class="error">' . implode('<br />', $error) . '</span> <br /><br />'; echo $errorMessage;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$error`  array is indexed, so you should use:

```
foreach ($error as $e){

}
```

Comment: Yeah you're right. I do too much OOP I guess ;). I have checked your answer, it's correct +1.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're checking if the error array **IS EMPTY**. If there's any error messages, it won't be empty, and you'll skip the entire message building block.

```
if (!empty ($error)){
    ^---- if NOT EMPTY
```

Comment: There is if-else in his code: if error is empty - not show errors, other way display all of them. I don't see error there